# Undefined reference error when using .a static library in Qt creator for android

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, undefined-reference

I'm new to Qt and now I'm using Qt creator to develop android application in Win7 OS.

The problem is when I try to call function in the .a library provided by an external company, there are undefined reference errors.

I've already told him my ndk revision and android cpu architecture, and then he re-compiled and gave me this .a file.

My Qt version is `Qt 5.3.2` for Android, and the ndk is `r10d`.

The error message:

```
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:158: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)'
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:161: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'
Makefile:79: recipe for target 'libuntitled.so' failed
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
D:/android/tools/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
collect2.exe: eooro: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The strange thing is that my ndk wasn't even installed in this directory!

Can any figure out why the errors occured?